# Output issue whilst using a try statement in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, printing, try-catch

My .jsp files are not outputting characters when I use out.println inside a try statement. For example:

```
out.println("testing123");
try { 

connectionDB = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, userDB, passDB);
psDB = connectionDB.prepareStatement(sql);
rsDB = psDB.executeQuery();
out.println("hello");
while(rsDB.next()){ 
    out.println("yay");
 }


} catch (Exception errorMessage) {


}
```

It will output "testing123" to the page but It will not output "hello" why is this, and how do I fix this? All help is appreciated. Remember this is a .jsp page.

Comment: @Emmett.. you can use HTML for output..    <%=variablename%>.. Also in your case you might have Exception in your Database connection code.. please check it.. by printing the exception inside catch block.. you haven't printed any exception message.

Comment: @Emmett: I bet you ran into the `catch` block, but as you completely ignore any possible exception it is impossible to know!

Comment: also try adding `out.println(errorMessage);` on you catch and check the output

Comment: @home you are right, I put an out.println in catch and its printing it out, I'm new to Java, how do I find out what the exception is exactly? What do I write in catch?

Comment: @Emmett: add a `e.printStackTrace()` and the exception will show up in the console (not on the web page).

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be eating the exception in your try/catch. It seems there is some exception happening in your try block and execution is not reaching to the statement

```
out.println("hello");
```

Try to print the stacktrace and correct the code so that execution is successful.

Answer (score 0):

This works  so you must have Exception in your Database code.

```
try{
out.println("hello there!");
   }
  catch(Exception e ){
e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have error in your Database code.
try this code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
............................
......
...
..
.

try { 

connectionDB = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, userDB, passDB);
stmt = connectionDB.createStatement();
rs = psDB.executeQuery("SELECT * from tblpost");
while(rs.next()){ 
    out.println(rs.getString("column_Name"));
 }


} catch (Exception errorMessage) {
out.println("error");
}
```

if you find it hard try to watch this [Database Connection and JSP Display](http://youtu.be/6iJusGSX3no)